# Use 2 different font sizes on combobox form elements

Tags: theming

In a form combobox, is it possible to have each combo box element have 2 different font sizes?

Blue (like the sky)
Yellow (like the sun)
Green (like the mix of the above)

The color names would display using a 16px font.
The text in parentheses would display using a 11px font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's possible in HTML & CSS flavour you are using, it is. There are two ways:

- Purely CSS one, [described at w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attribute_value.asp) and not really belonging to this site as it's Drupal independent.
- Class way - to get more flexibility and compatibility, add classes to your `<option>` tags inside your `<select>`. You can do this implementing [theme_select()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/theme_select/7) in your theme. You would need to replace [form_select_options()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_select_options/7) with your own function providing similar functionality, or parse original one's output to add your classes.